# How to display all elements of LinkedList?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, linked-list

In this linked list, the loop only dispalys the first two numbers (67,175).  How to use all elements of LinkedList and printout them all? Where's mistake in this code?

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public void insert(int data) {
        Node direction = new Node(data);
        direction.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = direction;
        } else {
            Node following = head;
            while (following.next == null) {
                following.next = direction;
            }
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        Node direction = head;
        while (direction != null) {
            System.out.println(direction.data);
            direction = direction.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted so much?  The mistake may be obvious to some, but this is not a reason to DV.   The problem is explained and the code is provided.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes but it is also important to show that you have put in some effort.

Comment: @Goion Like what?  The code is here, which is a lot more than most questions asked here.  I somehow think that debugging is just not taught.

Answer (score 3):

Your `insert` method is incorrect. This

```
Node following = head; 
while (following.next == null) {
    following.next = direction;
}
```

should be something like

```
Node following = head;
while (following.next != null) {
    following = following.next;
}
following.next = direction;
```

your current method only supports two nodes. You need to first follow to the end of the list and then *append* the new `Node`.